# Spring Boot Rest : Error 404 not found when sending simple get request via Postman?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman

I'm new postman, just installed it. I have spring boot simple app build with maven
and run in embedded tomcat through STS.
I'm try send get request:

```
http://localhost/9009/locations/Cntry
```

Here is the code from the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("locations")
@Slf4j
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    LocationService  locationService;
    
    @GetMapping("Cntry")    
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return locationService.getdCountries();
    }
```

I'm getting 404 error from postman when clicking send:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-09T03:40:36.764+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/9009/locations/Cntry"
}
```

I have 401 error before and I fixed it by comment spring security from pom file (I didn't
implement security yet). Ideally the spring security should be uncomment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your postman URL wrong. And correct the URL at controller level.

```
@GetMapping("/Cntry")

@RequestMapping("/locations")
```

9009 port number that's should come as below.

And confirm your PORT number correct or not by default it will run at 8080 if you want customize running port run then Add below configuration in application properties file.

```
server.port=9009

http://localhost:9009/locations/Cntry
```

Comment: THe port is my mistake yes it should be after ":". I thought spring add the forward slash for me. Do I need  to add myself ?

Comment: Controller will recognize that URL better add / in class level also

Comment: And check your running port number correct or not

Comment: I added "/" on both and it's working now, I get different error now.